# Creating push() method for Stack class with Node class

Tags: java, stack

I'm doing an assignment that I have to create my own Stack class using a Node class, I'm doing the push() method. Here is my code:

For class Node:

```
class Node{
    //attributes
    private String data;
    private Node next;

    //basic constructor
    Node(){

    }

    Node(String data){
        this.data = data;
        this.next = null;
    }

    //accessors
    public String getData(){
        return this.data;
    }
    public Node getNext(){
        return this.next;
    }

    //mutators
    public void setData(String tmpData){
        this.data = tmpData;
    }
    public void setNext(Node tmpNext){
        this.next = tmpNext;
    }
```

This is the method push I did so far:

```
class MyStack{
    //attributes
    private Node top;

//constructor
MyStack(){
    this.top = null;
}

//method to push a node into the stack
public void push(Node node){
    Node next = node.getNext();
    next = this.top;
    this.top = node;
}
public void print() {
        // Check if it's empty
        if (this.top == null) {
            System.out.println("Stack is empty.");
        } else {
            Node tmp = this.top;
            while(tmp != null) {
                System.out.print(tmp.getData()+ " ");
                tmp = tmp.next;
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

The main class that I use for testing:

```
class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyStack stack = new MyStack();
        stack.push(new Node("1"));
        stack.push(new Node("2"));
        stack.push(new Node("3"));
        stack.print();
        }
    }
```

Can you guys have a look at my push method, because when I print, the only value I get is 3, I want the output to be 3 2 1. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run this in the debugger, and you will see:

```
//method to push a node into the stack
public void push(Node node){
    Node next = node.getNext(); //If node is a new node, next is going to be null 
    next = this.top; // here you are just setting the variable you declared about to this.top. This erases setting next to node.getNext()
    this.top = node; // here you are setting this.top to node. You need to first set node.next = top
}
```

What you want is:

```
//method to push a node into the stack
public void push(Node node){
    node.setNext(this.top);
    this.top = node; // now node is the top, and node.next is the previous top
}
```

Make sure to set node.next first, or you won't be able to connect node to all the rest of the nodes in the stack

Comment: If this answers your question, please check the checkmark next to the answer